# cache doesn't update in real-time

Tags: node.js

I'm having a problem with the cache in my Node.js Express application. I'm using node-cache, and my issue is that the cache doesn't update in real-time.

To explain further, I have 3 tasks in cache, I run the application, and then I create one more task. I call the "get all" route, and it only returns 3 tasks. If I stop and restart the application, it updates the cache, meaning it returns 4 tasks.

I've done quite a bit of research, but I couldn't be sure. Should the cache be updated in real-time? Did I do something wrong?

Here's the relevant code:

```
@Post('create')
@Middleware(new RateLimiter(manyRequest).getMiddleware())
 async create(
  req: Request,
  res: Response
) {
  const createTask = new CreateTask(new PrismaManageRepository());
  const userId = req.context.userId._id

 try {
  const { task } = await createTask.execute({
    ...req.body,
    ...{ userId: userId },
  });     

  this.cache.del(this.taskCacheKey);

  // I try this too: 
  this.cache.set(this.taskCacheKey, task, (60 * 60 * 24));

  return { task: res.status(201).json(TaskViewModel.toHTTP(task)) };
} catch (err) {
  return this.errorResponse(res, err as Error);
}
```

}

```
@Get("all")
@Middleware(new RateLimiter(fewRequest + 2).getMiddleware())
 getAllTasks = async (
  req: Request,
  res: Response
) => {
 const cachedTasks = this.cache.get(this.taskCacheKey);    
 if (cachedTasks) {
  return res.status(200).json(cachedTasks);
}

const queryAllTasks = new QueryAllTasks(new PrismaTaskQueryRepository());
const userId = req.context.userId._id;

try {
  const { tasks } = await queryAllTasks.execute(userId);
  const tasksData = tasks.map(TaskViewModel.toHTTP);

  this.cache.set(this.taskCacheKey, tasksData);

  return res.status(200).json(tasksData);
} catch (err) {
  return logger.error(err);
}
};
```

Here's the link to the project repository: https://github.com/Lucasvmarangoni/TaskList

- /server/src/http/controllers

I hope to achieve having the cache updated in real-time or to understand whether this should or should not happen. And what was my mistake.

Comment: I do not see the definition for `taskCacheKey`. Hope you have declared a `constant` variable and set the value for `taskCacheKey` your controller or config file.

Comment: Yes, I declareted in BaseController:

   export abstract class BaseController {
      protected cache = new NodeCache({
       stdTTL: 60 * 60 * 48, 
       checkperiod: 5, 
       useClones: false 
    });
     protected taskCacheKey = 'allTasks';
     protected trashCacheKey = 'allTrash'
     protected userCacheKey = 'me'

Comment: Ok. Please see the modified code below in the **Answers**

Answer (score 0):

Please try this snippet.

```
@Post('create')
@Middleware(new RateLimiter(manyRequest).getMiddleware())
async create (
   req: Request,
  res: Response
) {
  const createTask = new CreateTask(new PrismaManageRepository());
  const userId = req.context.userId._id;

try {
  const {  task  } = await createTask.execute({
      ...req.body,
      ...{ userId: userId },
    });

    const cachedTasks = this.cache.get(this.taskCacheKey) || [];
    cachedTasks.push(TaskViewModel.toHTTP(task));

    this.cache.set(this.taskCacheKey, cachedTasks, 60 * 60 * 24);

    return res.status(201).json({ task: TaskViewModel.toHTTP(task) });
  } catch (err) {
    return this.errorResponse(res, err as Error);
  }
}
```